# Application Installation failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, installation, apk

When I attempted to run one of my projects,this I get this error message:

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE.
```

It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

I tried to press ok and uninstall the existing application but this is not solve the problem, I got many errors

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error show because your device for test the application doesn't have enough storge for install 
The app. So clean and delete some files and try again to install the app